# Elementary number theory digit sum question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Define $f(x)$ as the digit sum function in base $10$; Then, I am tasked with finding solutions to equation:

$$x = 2017f(f(x))\;.$$

My first idea was to use the congruence $x\equiv f(x) \bmod 9$ to obtain $x\equiv f(f(x)) \bmod 9$, hence $x-f(f(x))=9a$, for $a\in\mathbb Z$.
Then, solving for $x$ yields from the first equation
$x=2017a/224$, and this does yield solutions subject to the condition that $x$, $f(f(x))\ge0\in\mathbb Z$ when different values of $a$ are put in the general solution.

However, the solutions obtained actually satisfy the given equation for $a = 224n$, $n\in[0,9]$ only, and all solutions with $n\ge10$ do not satisfy it. Why is it so? Is there some better way to solve it?

Comment: where does $224$ come from?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @ZoeAllen substituting from x-f(f(x))=9a in the equation given in the problem.

Comment: letting $f(f(x))=\frac{a}{224}$ and then searching for solutions with $a=224n$ is just a more convoluted way of letting $f(f(x))=n$ and checking for each $n$.

Comment: Exactly, the congruence isn’t helpful in this, which is why I asked what other approach there could be to solve this

Comment: for $x=2017 $, $f( 2017)=10$ and $f(10)=1$ so that  $ x = 2017f(f(x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digit sum is like log, numbers have to get much larger for their digit sum to increase a little bit. Intuitively, this means that for a number to still be large after taking the digit sum twice, that number must be enormous- far larger than 2017 times the digit sum. This allows us to place an tight enough upper bound on how big $n=f(f(x))$ can be that we can just check everything below it.

For a number to have a digit sum $\ge n$ it must have at least $\frac{n}{9}$ digits, so in particular it must be $\ge 10^{n/9-1}$. So
$$x \ge 10 \uparrow(\frac{1}{9}10\uparrow(\frac{f(f(x))}{9}-1)-1)$$
So by substituting $x = 2017n , f(f(x))=n$
$$2017n \ge 10 \uparrow(\frac{1}{9}10\uparrow(\frac{n}{9}-1)-1)$$
If we rearrange this to be about logs instead of exponentials we get:
$$\log_{10}(\log_{10}2017+\log_{10} n + 1)+1 = \log_{10}\frac{1}{9} + \frac{n}{9}$$
Plot this in a grapher and you'll be able to see the RHS grows much more quickly, and any $n \ge 25$ is impossible.

Comment: You have a single $z$ which i guess should be $n$.